# Inputting results of a correlation on ggplot2 figure in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, correlation

I am trying to display the results of a correlation on a ggplot2 figure within a shiny app. I am using the iris dataset for this example. Specifically I want the correlation of the two variables being called by the `x` and `y` inputs. And I can figure out exactly what I am doing wrong. I keep getting the error:

> Warning: Error in cor.test.default: not enough finite observations

However, I know that this is not the case when I try evaluating the relationship outside the shiny app:

```
cor.test(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Width, alternative = "two.sided", method="spearman")
```

I've wrapped my `cor.test` call within a `reactive` function and I am trying to display an element using `geom_text`. Below are both my ui.R and server.R code.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong here?

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


dataset <- iris

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Iris Data Explore"),

  sidebarPanel(

    selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),
    selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[4]]),
    selectInput('species', 'Species', levels(dataset$Species), "virginica"),
    selectInput('color', 'Color', c('None', names(dataset))),

    checkboxInput('smooth', 'Smooth'),
    checkboxInput('line', 'Line')
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot')
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    filter(iris,Species==input$species)
  })

  cordf <- reactive({
    cor.test(as.numeric(input$x), as.numeric(input$y), alternative = "two.sided", method="spearman")
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes_string(x=paste0("`",input$x,"`"),
                                      y=paste0("`",input$y,"`")
                                      )) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_text(data=cordf(), aes(x=mean(input$x), y=mean(input$y), label=paste0(cordf$estimate))) +
      ggtitle(paste0(input$species))

    if (input$color != 'None')
      p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color)


    if (input$smooth)
      p <- p + geom_smooth(aes(group=1))
    if (input$line)
      p <- p + geom_line(aes(group=1), colour='seagreen')

    print(p)

  }, height=500)

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `dataset` is not even defined in your function `cordf()`, hence the error "not enough finite observation".

The other problem is you can't just do `mean(input$x)` since `input$x` is just some string like `Sepal.Length`. I also think you want `annotate` rather than `geom_text`.

The modified `server.R` is below. I am not familiar with shiny so not sure if the way it is done is best practice.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    filter(iris,Species==input$species)
  })

  cordf <- reactive({
    dataset<-dataset();
    cor.test(as.numeric(dataset[,input$x]), as.numeric(dataset[,input$y]), alternative = "two.sided", method="spearman")
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dataset<-dataset()
    p <- ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x=paste0("`",input$x,"`"),
                                      y=paste0("`",input$y,"`")
                                      )) +
      geom_point() +
      annotate("text", x=mean(dataset[,input$x]),y=mean(dataset[,input$y]), label=cordf()$estimate) +
      ggtitle(paste0(input$species))

    if (input$color != 'None')
      p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color)


    if (input$smooth)
      p <- p + geom_smooth(aes(group=1))
    if (input$line)
      p <- p + geom_line(aes(group=1), colour='seagreen')

    print(p)

  }, height=500)

})
```